# New dart file doesn't use flutter?

Tags: class, dart, flutter

I'm using classes from a new dart file in flutter, but it doesn't use the same dependencies and autocompletes as my main.dart file even after importing `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';` and `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more? What makes you think it doesn't zse dependencies? Which folder did you put the file? What's the current/expected behavior?

Comment: It's added to the lib folder with main.dart. For example when I add a new Scaffold it doesn't present a list of available properties with appropriate colons, semicolons, or commas.

Comment: The examples have these files in the `web/` directory. `main.dart` usually is also expected in ’web/`

Comment: Are you using IntelliJ?

Comment: Yes. I'm using IntelliJ.  Should all my files end in '.dart'?

Answer (score 0):

I refactored my new files as dart files and they all ended with `.dart`.  This wasn't an explicit direction on any of the tutorials.